# C# PowerShell Start-Command FilePath does not find my C driver

Tags: c#, powershell, command

I am writing C# application which is made for execute some file in some directories but when I try type my dir path to "Start-Process" with "AddParameter" command it gives this error ;

> 'Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'C' does not exist.'
> DriveNotFoundException: Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'C' does not exist.

Set-Location command can find the 'C:' path, the below command doesn't give any error ,

```
ps.AddCommand("Set-Location").AddParameter("Path", "C:\\Users\\User1\\Documents\\exectuteDir\\").Invoke();
```

but this one throws a error,

```
ps.AddCommand("Start-Process").AddParameter("NoNewWindow").AddParameter("FilePath", "C:\\Users\\User1\\Documents\\exectuteDir\\some.exe")
```

Thanks in advance

I tried with PS shell in order to correct my path dir and it is normal moreover I did it with "Set-Location" command and there was no problem but to get there but after "Set-Location" "Start-Process" gives same error again

Comment: You need to show the exact code and paths you are entering. Most likely the problem is with paths (quotes, extra characters, escaping, etc.).

Comment: ps.AddCommand("Start-Process").AddParameter("NoNewWindow").AddParameter("FilePath", "C:\\Users\\Sanberk\\Documents\\platform-tools_r33.0.1-windows\\adb.exe").Invoke(); @bahrep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `'Process'` library to put command on command-line.

**Using the PS hard for me and I think when PS called from application it starts on different OS layer therefore you can't execute whatever you want.**

Thanks